# Are there any L2-acquisition pedagogies based on the structure of L1-learning?

Tags: teaching-methods

The L2 classes I've experienced seem to be pragmatically focused on giving the student a combination of useful phrases, pronunciation, vocabulary, grammar, and even contextual/cultural information. Has anyone developed one that progresses as close as possible to L1-acquisition, for example, mastery of pronunciation, then basic limited vocabulary largely through interaction and participation and mastery over basic grammatical "parameters" (i.e., subject verb object order), then the basic conversational fluency of a kindergartener, then introducing reading, writing, and basically proceeding as a native speaker would through school, with lessons in spelling, reading, writing, more advanced grammar, idioms and social aspects?

Comment: Asher's Total Physical Response method, favored by Krashen for absolute beginners, was inspired by infant acquisition and resembles it somewhat, though not in the analytical progression you're proposing.  Both Krashen and Asher, I think, would be skeptical of the idea that explicit teaching and conscious analysis are necessary; their approach would be more like "try and understand simple utterances and interactions first; try and understand books later; and in both stages absorb the grammar/vocab/idioms unconsciously, through exposure".

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the immersion setting is most similar to L1 acquisition... and more so if the immersion class is teaching content vs solely teaching language. IB World Schools teach the target language in an immersion model by teaching 1) through the language, 2) about the language, and 3) to use the language - basically content instruction mixed with analysis of language parts to result in proficiency.